# find pair of node which adds to k in BST

Tags: c, data-structures

This is an interview question.
given a complete BST , find all pairs of nodes whose values adds to given sum k. no extra space should be used and time should be O( n) and best modification is nonot allowed.
Interviewer gave 15 min to come up with algo and code.
I am able to see other solutions but unable to find any which satisfy given constraints

Comment: Please explain some of the other solutions you have been able to come up with.

Comment: Do in order first and then on sorted array find pairs. But this does not satisfy space constraint

Comment: The only way to meet the space constraint is to assume parent pointers.  You could also use the Schorr-Waite algorithm, but even this one assumes 2 bits of data in each BST node.  The idea of starting at both ends simultaneously and advancing in order and alternately toward the middle is good.  15 minutes to fully code C for this is a big demand.

Answer (score 0):

No extra space ?  To walk the tree you need some stack... unless the nodes have parent pointers... so let's assume you can use some stack.  Clearly, if you had the values in ascending order, you could find all pairs that sum to 'k'.  So: walk the tree to the smallest, constructing an **explicit** stack -- ie, *not* recursing.  Duplicate the stack.  Now you can run two walks from there, in ascending order.

---

On further thought, suppose we run an in-order traversal, at each stage of which we have a value which we call `l`, and a reverse in-order traversal with current value `r`.  At any given point we have `s == l + r`, and we have already considered everything to the left of `l` and to the right of `r`.  If `s < k`, we advance to the next (larger) `l`, if `s > k` we step back to the next (smaller) `r`, and if `s == k` we have an answer.  (I guess we can assume that all values in the tree are unique, but if not we may have to consider several instances of a given `l` and `r` which give `k`.

The key to implementing this is a forward scan function:

```
  int forw(node* root, int l, int r, int k)
```

which first searches for node `l`, and then proceeds until `l + r >= k`.

And a similar function moving the other way.

These can be very efficiently implemented with an explicit stack for each one, which avoids having to first recurse down to (re)find the tree position of `l` or `r`... and I point out that the explicit stacks use no **extra** memory compared to the recursive function approach -- indeed, probably use **less** stack :-)

Further, the refinding of the tree position would make that, arguably, worse than O(n) -- adding a number of O(log(n)), one for each time the forward and backward scans are restarted.

Comment: The challenge here is to use no extra space and you are suggesting two explicit stacks??

Comment: The explicit stacks use no more space than recursing to walk the tree.  If one cannot use that much stack, one cannot walk the tree.

Comment: You could use two coroutines.  Or two threads... which comes to the same thing... but might also fail a very strict "no **extra** storage" requirement :-)

Comment: Somewhere I have read that this can be done by using inorder and reverse inorder traversal but could not understand how

Comment: As you move forwards from the smallest value, you need to move backwards from the largest to find the next candidates.  If you construct a reverse in-order traversal, which starts from a given value, and make it stop when it reaches a value which produces a sum <= k, you have a solution which uses stack (implicitly) to do the outer loop in-order and the inner-loop reverse in-order -- with the small disadvantage of the implied search for the starting node each time you enter the reverse in-order scan.  With an explicit (as opposed to implicit) stack, you avoid the implied search.

Answer (score 0):

It's theoretically impossible to use constant space and do it in constant number of passes without any additional properties.

Let's say that there are k pairs that add up to the target sum. In the worst case k is in O(n). e.g., 1, 1, 1, 1, ,1 ,1 ,1 ,1 ,1 ,1. and the target sum is 2.

If you are doing only constant number of passes, you need to remember (even if it's an efficient representation) the information about other nodes to enumerate the pairs that sum up to the target value. If you only want to use constant space (i.e, cannot afford to remember), then you have to do multiple passes (each pass may be sublinear) in the order of n to enumerate all the pairs that sum up to the target value. I can't see any getting around it.

If there are no duplicates, it's trivial to do it in o(n log n) without using additional memory. Since it's a complete binary tree, you can efficiently represent it as an array (2i + 1 - left child, 2i + 2 - right child, i / 2- parent). So you get free parent pointers. But this property is not required to do it in n long n, in this case.

even if you sort the elements you are going over the liner time complexity limit.